# Chromedriver Version Compatibility: Seeking Advice for Chrome Browser 119.0.6045.125

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, browser, selenium-chromedriver

I'm facing an issue with Chromedriver version compatibility. My Chrome browser is version 119.0.6045.125, while the closest Chromedriver version available is 119.0.6045.105. I'm unsure if I can use the available Chromedriver version or where to find the correct one. Seeking insights and solutions for this compatibility mismatch.

I've checked the official Chromedriver download page and found that the latest available version is 119.0.6045.105, which doesn't match my Chrome browser version. I'm uncertain if using this slightly older Chromedriver version would cause any compatibility issues.

I attempted to download Chromedriver from the official website, but the closest version available is 119.0.6045.105, not matching my Chrome browser version (119.0.6045.125). I'm looking for guidance on whether using this version difference could lead to problems or if there's a recommended solution.

Answer (score 2):

Only the major versions need to match for compatibility. So in your case versions 119 needs to match.

If you match major.minor.patch, so 119.0.6045, then you have a *perfect* match.

The last numerals, so 125 and 105 respectively, are build numbers, and will only match by coincidence.

Comment: Here you can download the latest chromedriver: https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable

Answer (score 2):

this solution will work every chrome driver version u will ever encounter in future **119, 120, 121 and so on**

1. In your terminal type,  pip install chromedriver-py==119.0.6045.105 and execute. (Version depends on the updates to come. Chang the version if required)
2. After installation, import the service path as =>
   from chromedriver_py import binary_path
3. Pass the binary path to the chromedriver as follows:

```js
from chromedriver_py import binary_path
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(executable_path=binary_path), options=options)
driver.get("Any URL of your choice")
```

Cheers you are good to go now !!

Answer (score 0):

if you go to the Chromedriver website it has the message that redirects you to Chromedriver above 115
https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/
download your Chromedriver according to your OS and use it in the constructor PATH

Answer (score 0):

To download ChromeDriver version 119.0.6045.105 for Chrome browser on Linux 64-bit, use the following link: https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/119.0.6045.105/linux64/chromedriver-linux64.zip

Comment: Is there a chance you can provide a link to 119.0.6045 on win64? I can't seems to find it anywhere.